# Difference between skinning, coloring and theming in Flex

Tags: css, apache-flex, actionscript-3

Please explain me the difference between skinning, coloring and themes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll give it a shot.

Skinning usually refers to the process of creating a CSS style sheet which changes the visual look look of components used within your application.

However, when you create a custom skin for a Spark component, it refers to creating a skin class (either in MXML or ActionSCript) which changes the layout of the components.

So, 'skin' is used in two different contexts there.

When you create a theme, it is usually a combination of CSS Styles, custom skin classes, and other related assets (PNG, FXG, etc..) all wrapped up in a single SWC.

"Coloring" is a term I've never heard used in relation to Flex development, so I would call it meaningless.

More information about [creating themes](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f85.html).

More iformation about [CSS in Flex](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf62883-7ff2.html)

More information about [Styles and themes](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fee.html).

Comment: Thank you @www.Flextras.com for clear explanation.I think, coloring means just coloring the component or background by using their color properties.

Comment: "Skinning usually refers to the process of creating a CSS style sheet which changes the visual look look of components used within your application." I usually tend to call that styling instead of skinning but yes, it's kind of nipticking here. Good answer overall

Comment: Well, "coloring" could make some sense in Spark.. there are a couple of global styles (themeColor, symbolColor, ecc.) that are used by the default Spark skin classes, using a subsystem that can "colorize" some part of the skin based on those global styles.. probably for this reason the spark skin looks very "grayscale" by default.